Can I notch a replacement top plate to accomodate existing anchor bolts?
I have to replace a rotten 2x8 top plate where a roof meets a block wall, and I'm going to have to lift the joists to fit the new top plate in, however there's some existing anchor bolts and I can't imagine I'll be able to lift the joists enough to get my new top plate between them and the anchor bolts. I'm not sure that my description or terminology is great, so I've attached a rough sketch to help. My question is, can I notch the board where the anchors are so I can slide it in, and maybe add large washers onto the anchor bolts to make up for it?
As a side note, the joist ends are pretty rotten where they meet the top plate, and if there's an acceptable way to cut them back and replace instead of sistering like I was planning, then that would also solve my problem. I'm using the term "joist" here for the boards that are laying directly on the top plate. These boards run horizontally from a massive center beam that spans the length of the building.
Thanks


I went to take a photo for this but the area is so dark and cramped that I really couldn't get anything useful.

Is reading this right, notching/drilling the top plate on top of a block wall should be okay.  The mention of anchor bolts on a top plate might mean they are required to anchor the top plate down, so adding big flat washers/steel plates might be needed.

How far can you lift the joists?

I've only just gotten the jacks setup but based on the overall length of the joists and my gut feeling, I'll be surprised if I can get them a full inch off the top plate.

Barring any concerns about lateral stiffness in the plate, notching closely to the bolt and using adequate washers will do just fine, especially if you were to counterbore the washers say 1/4" so the plates can't slip. Otherwise, torque them down until they crush into the wood a bit, and consider using two or three washers to span the gap more robustly.
                               ___
_____________________         |   |         ____________________
                     |__==================_|
                             ||   ||
                             ||   ||
                             ||   ||

If any part of the wall relies on that plate for stability, deep notches are a problem. I wouldn't think that's the case over concrete, though.

Some of the issue here is unknown, as if this was in Florida, (or any location where uplift must be mitigated) there would be no reason to counter bore. Generally notching and using big washers is an acceptable method of repair. I would say the answer is the best solution, given what we know about the structure.   I might add that correcting the problem that caused the rot should be addressed if it hasn't already.

The building really needs an entire metal roof replaced to truly address the issue. This was discovered right in the middle of me doing a full bathroom remodel, so I have to finish it first then get some funds to rapidly start on the roof, but that's a whole other question thread. Suffice to say I'm not loving my life at the moment. Thanks everyone, for the help on this!
